# Need to understand how node.js has to be configured to return a javascript library

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, socket.io

Newbie question.  My browser is throwing an exception:

**"Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: `"http://localhost:9090/d3/d3.min.js"`.  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

My code has two libraries, socket.io and d3.  Node returns the socket.io library to the browser, but when d3 is requested, node returns the web page instead.  I evidently don't understand how to configure things to make this work.  (Why does node know how to serve socket.io but not d3?) Thanks!

Here's the code:

test_app.js:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')
  , watch = require('watch')
  , d3 = require('d3')

app.listen(9090);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/test_socket.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading the html file');
    }
    //res.writeHead(200);
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    res.end(data);
  });
}
```

test_socket.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9090');
  socket.on('hi there now', function (data) {  // message received from server
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });  // talk back to server?
  });
</script>

<body>hello</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the browser network console to see what the actual HTTP response looks like. It could be a 404 page or something.

Comment: Thanks, good idea, but it's a 200

Comment: OK, but what is the actual content of the response?

Comment: Ok your question helped.  I checked the content of the response to the d3 request and instead of being the library, it's the actual web page (test_socket.html).  I've edited my question accordingly.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am betting the actual response contains the content of your test_socket.html. The problem is that there is no exception rule for loading the javascript file, the server always responds to requests by sending test_socket.html. The socket.io javscript file works, however, because socket.io itself intercepts this request and serves the socketio.js file (look in your console, it should say "served static content socket.io" or something along those lines)

I find that it is a lot easier to let a prebuilt framework deal with these kind of issues.
Take a look at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-nodejs-and-websockets-to-build-a-chat-service--net-34482. It's the tutorial that I used to get started, which introduces you into node.js, npm, express, jade and socket.io. Should get you started on building your first Web 2.0 app quite nicely!

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's returning the contents of the html page instead.  I didn't know about the 'magic' that socket.io does.  I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: It's not really magic. The reason is that they also use that same url (domain.com/socketio.js) to route their communcation. All they do is intercept any request to that address, so that they can properly process it. If it is only a request to that specific url, without any added communication related data, it understands that the javascript file itself is being requested, and thus it happily serves it. Anyway, good luck with your app!

Comment: I can't figure out how to write the 'exception rule' you referred to, as socket.io appears to be essentially without documentation outside of one example.  I'm so close on this and spent so much time on it that it seems crazy to throw it all away and start over learning Express.  This is an important, but throwaway demo, so it doesn't need to have production-quality design patterns or code.

Comment: Express has some functions for this, where you can specify the route and also make a "public" dir, a place to put your css and javascript files. Any request that is made to this "public" dir, is simply served the requested file, istead of a normal test/html response.

In your quick and dirty approach, you will have to do something along the lines of: http://www.robsearles.com/2010/05/nodejs-tutorial-part-2-routing/. I.e. you create a specific route for the javascript file, and then seperately fetch and return that file.